# Objective C setters, help understanding the basics of objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am watching a demo and I realize that I don't understand a couple of basic things about programming style in objective c. The demo happens to be lecture 14 of Stanford's CS193P. See the code below to see what is confusing me. Has to do with setters, I think.

```
@synthesize photoDatabase = _photoDatabase;

- (void)setPhotoDatabase:(UIManagedDocument *)photoDatabase
{
    if (_photoDatabase != photoDatabase)
        _photoDatabase = photoDatabase;
}
```

This code is from 25:00 in the youtube video for [this lecture/Demo](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3lZj1Hlc1Iw). The synthesized property here called photoDatabase happens to be of the type UIManagedDocument.

My first question is, why should we use the underscore in @synthesize myProperty = _myProperty. I'm a bit confused about it, being new to programing in general. As of XCode 4 don't we synthesize in part to eliminate the need for the underscore when referring to this property?

My second question is what is the purpose of the setPhotoDatabase: method. I assume the lecturer is overriding this method. To what purpose exactly?

Comment: Hm. If you `@synthesize` the property, you don't need to implement it explicitly. And if you implement it manually, then you don't need to `@synthesize` it.

Comment: BTW, please **DO NOT post screenshots of text.** And pay attention to links. And don't paste YouTube links along with all the social media, referrer and other parameters. `?v=XXXXXX` is more than enough.

Comment: I have watched these videos myself and he does explain early on in the lectures (believe it could be 2 or 3) what the `@synthesize` does and why/when to use it.

Comment: @H2CO3 thanks I was in the middle of adding the code by hand when you did.

Comment: To answer the second question, as I've been through a few of Paul Hegarty's tutorials, he often overrides the setters and getters to show how to do it for students and occasionally to add additional functionality a bit further in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll tackle your first question... When you use synthesize a property, you are merely auto-creating the setter and getter for an instance variable. Say you have:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *title;
```

The synthesize:

```
@synthesize title;
```

Creates the following methods:

```
- (NSString) title;
- (void) setTitle:(NSString *)value;
```

Now within your class, you want to access the title property, you would do so by using either `title` or `self.title`. Even though these both appear to be the same thing, they are not. `title` accesses the instance variable itself, while `self.title` is accessing the "synthesized" method `- (NSString) title;`

Wouldn't it make things simpler if we had some sort of way to more easily distinguish between the two? Well that is exactly where `@synthesize title = _title;` comes in. It creates the standard setter and getter, but sets the instance variable to `_title` instead of `title`.

EDIT: Newer versions of Xcode (4.3 and above I believe) automatically include the `@synthesize <variable> = _<variable>` for you, so you needn't do this yourself.

Comment: I think I get it... Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The underscore is the default way the actual ivar is generated. 
It allows you to be kind of meta. 
Internal to your class you can reference them directly like this avoiding an unnecessary method call to the getter or setter. 
It also keeps the scope clear and allows you to use the same name as the property and the getter for the variable name of an argument in other method declarations. That makes it implicit that the argument to the method is intended to be related to that property. 
The underscore keeps the local variable from clashing with your ivar inside a method.

You could intentionally obscure your ivar name from subclass creators by manually synthesizing it as something very different.
The use of that is to protect the ivar from subclass creators in case the do something your SPI would not work with.

The purpose of a setter method like that is to conform with convention and with key value coding. It is used by other classes to set the ivar.

You can manually implement your own setter when you need to provide some functionality beyond what is synthesized for you. 
That could include data validation or triggering notifications or other things.

Answer (score 1):

Underscore is just a way to mark variable as instance variable, not method variable. It is a bad practice to use public members, so it is normal to use setters and getters. `@synthesize` generates getter and setter automatically, depending on keywords after `@property` keyword. It can generate `retain`(`strong` when using arc), `assign`(`weak` when using arc), etc. setters and getters.

Also you can override any of these autogenerated methods to add some logic. For example, you may want to print message to console every time this value changed or update view after changing property.